# Javascript regular expression to find any character other than floating point numbers in the input

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point

The user can provide any kind of data. I need to make sure the input string contains only floating point number. So I need to make sure the data contains only numbers or a dot (.) and return false if the input data has anything other than numbers or a dot. Can someone help me with the javascript regular expression? I tried searching a lot. But I could not find any help for my specific case.

```
So this should return characters for cases like
12.09a23
aa12.12
abcd
```

Update

I donot want to see if the input string has floating point number. I want to see if the input has anything other than floating point number. For example, if the input has 12.3aa23, I want to show the input has aa so this is an invalid input.

Comment: 12.34e56 is a valid number. Should this be flagged as invalid?

Comment: in my scenario, the data I need to validate is the currency. So I do not need to really check for exponential numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isDigit(str){
var n = str.search(/^(\d)*(\.)*(\d)*$/); 
return (n!==-1);
}
```

from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) and [here](https://regex101.com/) :-)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6o0v4or/)

Comment: feel free to remove the last regexp condition (  \.  ) if you don't want to match only a dot (which is likely)

Comment: Just a note: `i` option is redundant in the regex here since numbers do not have case.

Comment: @vivoconunxino, what ever input I give, the n value is always -1. what am I missing

Comment: ah I know, it returns -1 when fails, wait

Comment: Now should work, i changed return (n!==false) into return (n!==-1)

Comment: @vivoconunxino, This is serving my purpose.. Thanks a lot. But a humble request. This is not working for input .12 (a dot followed by 12). if possible can you include this scenario as well. This will be helpful for anyone refering to this post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/` regex to find floating point numbers in individual strings (thus, adding anchors). [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Also, here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB3lX8/1).

Snippet:

```js
if ("12.09a23".search(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/) != -1) {
  alert("Floating number detected! ")
}
else
{ 
  alert("Floating number not detected! Invalid data inside string: " + "12.09a23".replace(/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?/g, '')) 
}
```

Comment: I donot want to see if the input string has floating point number. I want to see if the input has anything other than floating point number. For example, if the input has 12.3aa23, I want to show the input has aa so this is an invalid input.

Comment: I updated my post with a snippet showing how my regex can be used for your purpose.